# How can I get rid of duplicates in Resource.Designer.cs?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin Studio 4.0.12.  I had a layout resource that I renamed and now I have two properties of the same name in the partial class Layout.  I tried deleting the layouts from the folder then putting in new layouts, but then the two properties simply change to the new name of the layout.  Where does the code generator get the information to generate this class?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

FAQAnswerTemplate is the duplicated property

```
public partial class Layout
    {

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030009
        public const int FAQAnswerTemplate = 2130903049;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030008
        public const int FAQQuestionItem = 2130903048;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030000
        public const int ContactView = 2130903040;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030001
        public const int Events = 2130903041;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030002
        public const int EventSessionItem = 2130903042;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030003
        public const int FAQ = 2130903043;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030004
        public const int FAQAnswerTemplate = 2130903044;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030005
        public const int MainView = 2130903045;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030006
        public const int SplashScreen = 2130903046;

        // aapt resource value: 0x7f030007
        public const int SubsidyCalc = 2130903047;

        static Layout()
        {
            global::Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues();
        }

        private Layout()
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the issue and fixed it.  He was the problem.  I was using "@+layout/Blah" which will add a resource to Resource.Designer.cs.  Add to that I already had a layout called blah, it then duplicates the property in the .cs file.

The whole reason I was using "@+layout/Blah" was because "@layout/Blah" was causing a "No resource found that matches the given name" compile error.

Well, the resolution for that is (as I found out and immediately had a bout of tourettes) regardless of the case of the name of the resource, when referencing it within a layout it has to be all lowercase.